# How to split a string in Bash?

Tags: bash

I have a variable `x` which contains a string like "2025-12-13-04-32 Hello StackOverflow programmers".

How can I split it in several variables like this:

```
d=2015
m=12
dy=13 
h=04
mi=32 
t="Hello StackOverflow programmers"
```

Answer (score 10, accepted):

**A single `read` command will do**:

```
input='2025-12-13-04-32 Hello stackoverflow programmers'

IFS='- ' read -r d m dy h mi t <<<"$input"
```

<sup>Note: `<<<` is a so-called [here-string](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/HereDocument?action=show&redirect=HereString), which allows providing a regular *string* [variable] via stdin, related to the multi-line [here-doc](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/HereDocument) (something starting with, e.g., `<<EOF`). Here it is the shorter and more efficient alternative to `echo "$input" | IFS='- ' read ...`</sup>

- `IFS='- '` causes read to split the input line into tokens by either a space or a `-`.
- Even though that would normally also break the string `'Hello stackoverflow programmers'` into 3 tokens, it doesn't here, because `read` assigns the *remainder* of the line to the *last* variable specified, in case there aren't enough variables to match the resulting tokens; thus, variable `$t` receives `'Hello stackoverflow programmers'`, as desired.

---

To **print the results**, use the following:

<sup>Note that `${!name}` is an instance of [variable indirection](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/006#Indirection) - accessing a variable through another variable that contains its *name*.</sup>

```
names=( d m dy h mi t )
for name in "${names[@]}"; do
  printf '%s=%s\n' "$name" "${!name}"
done
```

This yields:

```
d=2025
m=12
dy=13
h=04
mi=32
t=Hello stackoverflow programmers
```

---

A note on the **choice of approach**:

- `read` is great for field-based parsing based on a set of literal separator characters (a caveat is that *each* instance of a non-whitespace separator char. counts).

  - With `read -ra`, you can even read all tokens into an *array*, without having to know the number of tokens in advance.
- For more flexible parsing (based on a known number of tokens), consider use of `=~` with regular expressions, as in [Jahid's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/35086064/45375).

Comment: Okey it was a problem with my script it works fine. Thanks.

Comment: Here-string is not quite an equivalent of a pipe `echo blah | stuff` but rather an equivalent of a here-doc. Apart from that minor remark, your answer is definitely the best in OP's case.

Comment: @gniourf_gniourf. Thanks; I've added a reference to here-docs and changed 'equivalent' to 'alternative'.

Answer (score 5):

Using Bash regex:

```
#!/bin/bash
s='2025-12-13-04-32 Hello stackoverflow programmers'
pat="([0-9]+)-([0-9]+)-([0-9]+)-([0-9]+)-([0-9]+)[[:space:]]*(.*)"
[[ $s =~ $pat ]]
echo "${BASH_REMATCH[1]}"
echo "${BASH_REMATCH[2]}"
echo "${BASH_REMATCH[3]}"
echo "${BASH_REMATCH[4]}"
echo "${BASH_REMATCH[5]}"
echo "${BASH_REMATCH[6]}"
```

Output:

```
2025
12
13
04
32
Hello stackoverflow programmers
```

Comment: For me, it doesn't show "Hello stackoverflow programmers".

Comment: Okey it was a problem with my script it works fine. Thanks. I did for x in $(ls $1)

Comment: ++ for potentially more flexible parsing via `=~`; You could additionally create (and print) the individual variables as follows: `names=(d m dy h mi t); i=0; for (( i = 0; i < "${#names[@]}"; i++ )); do declare "${names[i]}=${BASH_REMATCH[i+1]}"; printf '%s=%s\n' "${names[i]}" "${!names[i]}"; done`; @Craxxurz: It's better [not to use `for` to parse command output](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/DontReadLinesWithFor)

Answer (score 1):

To automatically assign whitespace separated values to variable names, you could do this:

```
x="2025-12-13-04-32 Hello stackoverflow programmers"
read -r d m dy h mi <<< "$x"
```

But since the beginning of the string contains dash signs (-) you first have to replace them with whitespaces:

```
x="2025-12-13-04-32 Hello stackoverflow programmers"
x="$(echo "$x" | sed 's/-/ /g')"
read -r d m dy h mi <<< "$x"
```

Still you have to adjust the number of variable names ;-)

I would say this is what you want:

```
x="2025-12-13-04-32 Hello stackoverflow programmers"                                                                                        
x="$(echo "$x" | tr '-' ' ')"                                                                                                               
read -r d m dy h mi t <<< "$x"                                                                                                          
echo $d
2025
echo $m
12
echo $dy
13
echo $h 
04
echo $mi
32
echo $t
Hello stackoverflow programmers
```

Comment: Instead of an external sed call, you could do the replacement with a parameter expansion: `x="${x//-/ }"`.

Answer (score 0):

Using parameter substitution and `declare`:

```
#!/bin/bash
x="2025-12-13-04-32 Hello stackoverflow programmers"

Shift () {
    declare -g "$1=${copy%%-*}"
    copy=${copy#*-}
}

copy=$x

for var in d m dy h mi ; do
    Shift $var
done

mi=${mi%% *} # Remove the message
t=${copy#* }

for var in d m dy h mi t ; do
    echo $var ${!var}
done
```

Comment: Just a heads-up for people stuck with Bash _4.1 or lower_: `declare -g` is not supported; without `-g`, `declare` creates a _local_ variable inside a function.
Generally, simply omitting `declare` _also_ creates a global variable, but since a _parameter value_ is used as the variable _name_ here, `declare` is required.
An alternative that works down to (at least) Bash 3.x is to use `printf -v` to create the global variable: `printf -v "$1" %s "${copy%%-*}"`.